# ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

i'm using xamarin froms and trying to display an image with a url but i get this error

url be like "https://37.34.189.."

Android options:
HttpClient Implementation: Managed
SSL Implementation: Native TLS 1.2+

My code:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" Margin="0"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "{Binding ProfileImage}">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Comment: please format your code when posting.  Have you verified that the url returns a valid image and is reachable from your device?

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your response,
yes I have test the url and it's returns a valid image

Comment: can your device reach the url?  Have you tested loading it in mobile Chrome on the device?

Comment: I got an exception "ssl connection could not be established"

Comment: that sounds like a problem you need to fix on your server

Comment: I think that too, thank you